# Multiple colliding references in pyparsings MatchFirst

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

I'm building an interpreter for a scripting language. The individual components are working as expected, but when I use them in a delimited list for function arguments the parser resolves the one kind of argument to the wrong type.

Definitions are:

```
legalChars = alphanums + "-" + "_"
identifier = Word(legalChars)
boolean = CaselessKeyword("TRUE") | CaselessKeyword("FALSE")
number = Word(nums + "." + "-")
lparen = Literal("(").suppress()
rparen = Literal(")").suppress()
constant = number("NUMERIC") | quotedString("STRING") | boolean("BOOL")
operator = (Literal("==") | Literal("!=") | Literal(">") | Literal("<") | Literal(">=") | Literal("<="))("OPERATOR")

condition = Forward()
function = Forward()
attribute = (Word(legalChars) | Combine("[" + Word(legalChars+" ") + "]"))("ATTRIB")
variable = Combine("@" + identifier)("VAR") 
arg = function | condition | constant | attribute | variable
args = delimitedList(arg)
function <<= (identifier("FUNCTOR") + lparen + Optional(args)("ARGS") + rparen)("FUNCTION")
condition = variable + operator + (variable | constant)
```

The issue happens if I try to have a conditional in the function, like:

```
iff(@somevar=="Foo")
```

It won't interpret the conditional. If I try to parse it through `arg` or `args` it will interpret it as a `variable` not a `conditional`. I've tried the same thing using `^` to separate the values in `arg` but I get the same result.

Comment: Since `condition` is defined as a `Forward`, should `condition = ...` be `condition <<= ...`?

Answer (score 0):

As Paul pointed out, I had an error in my code. I was assigning the `condition` variable incorrectly.